# Entity Framework Core : connect to Oracle database

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-5

In a .NET 5.0 framework project, I have referenced the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.21.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.1" />
```

in `ConfigureSettings` method I have added this code:

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>((provider, options) =>
        {
            OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add("dev", "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = <host> )(PORT = 1521 )) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DEV ) ) )");
            options.UseOracle(connectionString);
        });

services.AddScoped(sp => (MyDbContext)sp.GetRequiredService<IMyDbContext>());

services.AddEntityFrameworkOracle();
```

Later in my service, I am trying to query a simple result:

```
await _dataContext.MyTable.CountAsync(cancellationToken)
```

but I get the following error (Error message is in German):

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12154: TNS: Angegebener Connect Identifier konnte nicht aufgelöst werden
>
> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): ORA-12154: TNS: Angegebener Connect Identifier konnte nicht aufgelöst werden

The same time I have created a connection in Visual Studio Server Explorer with the following Connection string:

```
Data Source=dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=***********;Unicode=True
```

and it's enough to get query data.

What do I wrong in my project setup?

Comment: You might want to try `HOST = dev` in your TNS connect string. Basically the connect string is simply incorrect and you have to get it right

Comment: Check this https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you! https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/omiting-tnsnamesora/ has solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

the problem has been solved by omiting TnsName in the connection string

https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/omiting-tnsnamesora/

after the change I have also removed this code line:

```
OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add
```